# Prevent SQL Injection using EXECUTE AS

Tags: sql-server-2005

Prevent SQL injection using `EXECUTE AS`

I was told that one of the ways to prevent SQL injection is creating a database user without login:

```
CREATE USER User1 WITHOUT LOGIN
Go

GRANT DELETE ON T1 to User1
Go

create proc [dbo].[t1]  (@ID  INT)
with execute as 'user1'
as 
begin

    declare @sql as varchar(500)
    SET @sql = 'delete from T WHERE ID = @ID'
    exec (@sql)

end
```

My question is how can we use the above procedure as User1 has not permission to login?

Comment: I'm also not sure how this prevents a SQL injection attack.  The above SP can't have SQL injection because there are no parameters but if there were parameters and they  were being concatenated into the sql string that is execed, there is still no prevention except the limited permissions given to User1.  So it doesn't prevent, say, somone inserting thousands of bogus records into your table using SQL injection.

Comment: I changed the code can you reformat please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed such technique.
You create a user without login, assing carefully chosen permissions to that user, and then apply the context of that user to either stored procedures or individual `execute` statements.

Because the user does not have a login, nobody can directly connect to the server under this user. You cannot also directly impersonate that user because you don't have the permission to do so. Under this scenario, the only way to "be" that user is executing a stored procedure or a command where the `execute as` clause has been added by the stored procedure creator (who, on contrary, does have the permission to impersonate the loginless user).

While this technique is exactly what you want in certain situations, I wouldn't use it to prevent SQL injections in the form you are showing in the question. This technique is useful when you have to allow your partially trusted users to provide input that is used in place of, say, object names or SQL keywords (i.e., when the user provides name of the table to work on, or when the user is allowed to construct their own `where` condition which you will then execute without analysis). But for the kind of things you are showing in the question, use [parametrized statements](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) on the client side, and parameters on the server side:

```
create proc [dbo].[t1]
  @ID  INT
as 
begin
  delete from T where ID = @ID;
end
```

(bad example btw; the parameter is `int`, so SQL injection is not possible even if you concatenate it.)

Comment: I just posted a bad example but trying to make sense http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Little-Bobby-Tables-SQL-Injection-and-EXECUTE-AS.aspx however, I do not understand this part. If user is not allowed to login, how a client application can execute a proc (how can we use impersonation)

Comment: OK @ID need to be varchar for SQL injection to occure. My bad thank you.

Comment: @SQLLearner You log in under a different user. Then you execute the stored proc, which temporarily changes your permissions to those assigned to the loginless user.